# I can't figure out why double digits are not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

I am trying to create a program where you could enter player's number and it will return his name. Everything is good with players whose jersey number is single digit, however it doesn't return anything for a player whose jersey number is double digits. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you for the helps in advance.

```py
    cimbom = input( "Player's Number: ")
players = {"10": "Belhanda",
             "89": "Feghouili",
             "20": "Emre",
             "7": "Onyekuru",
             "6": "Taylan"}
out = ""
for player in cimbom:
    out += players.get(player," ")
print(out)
```

Comment: Why the loop `for player in cimbom`? That is looping over the number digit by digit. It isn't clear what you expect that loop to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs from console are taken as `strings`. So, if you input `20`, then `cimbom` is equal to the *string* `"20"`.

Which means, when looping over `cimbom` using `for player in cimbom:`, the loop will loop over each character of "20" individually, namely, "2", then "0".